# Perl: Conditional code execution inside regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I'm aware of the so-called experimental `(?{ ... })` facility in Perl 5 to execute code as such `print` statements, setting global variables.

However, I have a need to:

1. refer to the matched string inside of the `(?{ ... })` block; and
2. depending on its value, execute some arbitrary code

**Desired Usage:**

```
$input =~ m/ (foo) 
               (?{ if (defined (\1) { process(\1) } }) 
              bar
          /x;
```

Note: There may obviously be gazillion alternatives to achieving the same effect (TMTOWDI) but I'm interested only in the above style, for now. Hence, the post.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example.

perldoc perlre:

> `$^N` contains whatever was matched by the most-recently closed group (submatch)

**test_extended_re_code.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @input = split /\n/, <<"END";
foo 123 bar
foo 456 bar
fo  789 bar
foo xyz bar
END

for my $input ( @input ) {
    $input =~ m/foo (\d+)(?{ process( $^N ) if $^N }) bar/;
}

sub process {
    my ($txt) = @_;
    print "Processing '$txt'\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
Processing '123'
Processing '456'
```

Comment: Cool! Can we also find out if `foo` matched but without the grouping/parentheses around `foo`?

Comment: Yes, same result if you remove the parens around foo.   Updated answer.